# Preview lightning email template content

Tags: lightning, email, template, preview

I need to preview an email template before sending it, but also need to be able to see the merged fields. The initial task I was able to accomplish using **/email/templaterenderer**. It's showing the merge fields now but now I need to **edit** the email body before sending it and I cannot figure a way to do that.

Also, it should be applied to multiple email templates.

So, is there any way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you expand on your last tidbit - "also, it should be applied to multiple email templates"? It seems like, before that, just a standard lighting email template should be fine as you can add to it when you compose an email in Salesforce.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I have a flow where the user will pass the template ID of which email template he needs to send. After a template is selected, some parameters are passed to a lightning component where I rendered an email preview. I couldn't find a way to get email content and display it other than templaterenderer.

My problem is that we have 100+ templates and the merge fields are not the same for all so it cannot be hardcoded. 

So, templaterenderer was fine until we got a request to be able to edit the preview.

Thanks.